# Type conversions without loss of precision

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion

I've just recently noticed some of the code in the framework I am working with converts certain variables to doubles and then back when they are accessed by the framework. In the C++11 standard, is this guaranteed to work without loss of precision for any integral types? If so, which? Are there any additional types that are universally safe for this kind of conversion in common implementations?

Also, is there any way to check at compile time that a conversion is safe in this way? Essentially I would like something like:

```
static_assert(T(double(T type))==type);
```

Comment: What types are you using in your own code? Is there a reason that you aren't using `double` to begin with to avoid these conversions?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The types are set by the framework (i.e. I can't change them). For instance, `m_type` is an `unsigned int` internally, but when it is accessed through the framework it is converted to a `double`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Additionally, I'm converting them back to the original type to save space. I am serializing them afterwards, and even with this conversion it is still taking up around a terabyte, so optimizations on this level count a great deal.

Comment: I don't think there is much that you can do with the internals of the framework.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I agree. My question is whether the conversion, for instance, of `unsigned int` to `double` back to `unsigned int` can ever be a  problem (i.e. can ever return something not bitwise identical to the original). If so, I'll just have to abandon the framework entirely and figure something else out. If not, then all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T(double(T_value))==T_value` is guaranteed when the range of integral type `T` is a subrange of the range of exact integral values of type `double`.

Since no implementation of `double` has 16 bits or less for the mantissa, and since as far as I know there's no extant C++ implementation with more than 16 bits per byte (the `CHAR_BIT` constant from `<limits.h>`), this guarantee holds for `char` and and the explicitly `signed` and `unsigned` variants.

Typically a `double` has some 50+ bits mantissa, and that's enough for the guarantee to hold also for 32-bit integral types, but not for 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I (mostly) figured out the second part of my question:

```
#include <limits>
static_assert(T(double(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()))==std::numeric_limits::max(),"ERROR MESSAGE.");
```