# Non-constant expression for static assertion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058979/type-conversions-without-loss-of-precision/39059888) I was trying to figure out at compile time if a particular conversion (of the type to `double` and back) for a particular fundamental type was safe or not.

Eventually, I figured out the following code:

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

template<class one>
class test {
    typedef typename one::value_type v; //My code actually takes std:: containers, not the type directly, so get the type.
    typedef std::numeric_limits<v> limits; //Easier to read

    static_assert(limits::max()==v(double(limits::max())),"MEANINGFUL ERROR MESSAGE"); //See if the conversion works correctly 
};
```

When it is declared with a "safe" type, like:

```
test<std::vector<int> > a;
```

It compiles just fine. But when it is compiled with a type that will not convert correctly, such as:

```
test<std::vector<unsigned long long> > b;
```

Rather than failing the assertion as I expected, it fails to compile with the error message (using g++ 4.7.1 and 5.3.0 with `--std=c++11`):

```
test2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class test<std::vector<long long unsigned int> >’:
test2.cpp:11:40:   required from here
test2.cpp:8:5: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
     static_assert(limits::max()==v(double(limits::max())),"MEANINGFUL ERROR MESSAGE");
```

I suppose that it is still getting the job done (not compiling when there's a problem, but I still can't figure out why `limits::max()==v(double(limits::max()))` doesn't count as a constant condition, and I don't really like the fact that it makes the error message less comprehensible. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: A constant expression cannot have undefined behaviour. If, say, `double(ULONGLONG_MAX)` is bigger than the original value, then attempting to convert the result back has UB, so it's not a constant expression.

Comment: @KerrekSB Ah, that makes sense. So, is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without invoking UB? Effectively I'm looking for the largest integer `N` such that all integers `i <= N` are exactly representable as a double.

Comment: I think that's what [`std::numeric_limits::digits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits) is for.

Comment: @KerrekSB `std::numeric_limits::digits` is great if `FLT_RADIX==2` but I'm not sure how to generalize it if i.e. `FLT_RADIX==10`. At least without a constexpr log function...

Answer (score 0):

My crappy solution I just came up with:

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

template<class one>
class test {
    typedef typename one::value_type v; //My code actually takes std:: containers, not the type directly, so get the type.
    typedef std::numeric_limits<v> limits; //Easier to read

    static_assert(double(limits::max())!=double(limits::max())+1),"MEANINGFUL ERROR MESSAGE"); //Once the value is large enough that integers are not exactly representable, x==x+1 for doubles. 
};
```

I'm still hoping I'll find a better solution, though. This feels wrong somehow and I'm not sure it'll work in all cases. At the very least I would need to handle floating point conversions separately.